# Significance and functionality of "?WSDL"

Tags: web-services, wsdl

What is the significance and functionality of "?WSDL" . When an URL with ?WSDL and the end is invoked for a web service call, is it possible for application to process the request or the function of ?wsdl is to publish the WSDL file only?

Answer (score 0):

When implemented, `?wsdl` returns the WSDL file only.

It is not implemented by all SOAP services, and in fact there is no standard that covers it.